# Adding car make model year country to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

this function is supposed to loop through a dictionary(database):

```
{ data_base = {
"Mercedes": [("E-class", 1970, "classic" , "Germany"),("Clk",     2000, "sport" , "Poland")]
"Fiat": [("Uno" , 1980, "coupe" , "Italy")]
"Jaguar" : [("S-type", 2000, "classic", "England"),("X-type", 2005,"luxury", "England")] }
```

Function accepts a database (above example), updates all other information to it. If a car is already in it and all attributes match, no duplication. Also, sort Asciibetically by car model. Function updates only, no returns.

```
functionX (data_base,make,model,year,style,country):
    for key,value in data_base.items():
        if key == make and value[0] != model: # condition to ensure update is not duplicate
            database[key].extend((model,year,style,country)):
```

Comment: How do I approach the asciibetical order??

Comment: okay, thanks. Any suggestions on the code?

Comment: sorting "in-place" for Mercedes: `data_base["Mercedes"].sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Can only use dictionary methods not (lambda...), this program will check if the input database could be updated (if the make,model,year,style,country are not already in it). Then we can add that to that dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

When looping over `data_base.items()`, `value` is not what you think it is. It is the list of models associated with a make of car. E.g.  `[("Uno" , 1980, "coupe" , "Italy")]` for the key `'Fiat'`. So when checking for a duplicate model, you need to iterate over that list to make sure the model is not found:

```
def functionX (data_base,make,model,year,style,country):
    for key, value in data_base.items():
        # first find all the models associated with the make 
        present_models = set(data[0] for data in value)
        if key == make and model not in present_models: # condition to ensure update is not duplicate
            database[key].extend((model,year,style,country))
```

Next point: you're not taking advantage of the fact that your database is a dictionary. There's no need to loop through all the key-value pairs when we know what key we're interested in. We can do the following:

```
def functionX (data_base,make,model,year,style,country):
    if make in data_base:
        present_models = set(data[0] for data in data_base[make])
        if model not in present_models:
            database[make].extend((model,year,style,country))

    else: # make not found so we can just add the info without worrying about duplication
        data_base[make] = [(model,year,style,country)]
```

`set(data[0] for data in data_base[make])` creates a set of the model names under the make. You can think of a set as a list containing no duplicates. It provides fast checking for whether an item is in the set (whereas for a list we have to check each item one-by-one). The syntax for creating this set uses list-comprehension in Python which you can read about here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Finally, sorting can be done pretty normally using `sort`. Each list of models contains tuples and tuples are sorted lexicographically (the first items are compared, if they're equal, the second items are compared and so on...) by default in Python. We want the list to be sorted by the first items in our tuples (the model) so we can just call `sort` on the list after adding the new item. In general, you can specify a predicate to use when sorting by setting the key parameter on `sort` (e.g. `sort(my_list, key=<some function>)`).

```
def functionX (data_base,make,model,year,style,country):
    if make in data_base:
        present_models = set(data[0] for data in data_base[make])
        if model not in present_models:
            database[make].append((model,year,style,country))
            sort(database[make])
    else: # make not found so we can just add the info without worrying about duplication
        data_base[make] = [(model,year,style,country)]
```

I also changed `extend` to `append` since you are only adding a single item.

This solution could be made more efficient if we utilize the fact the lists of models are already sorted. With that fact we can perform binary searches when checking if a model is present and when inserting a new model.

Comment: So you're saying looping is not mandatory?? I had the same feeling since we have a dictionary!

Comment: "present_models = set(data[0] for data in data_base[make])" could you please explain in simple words what this line does?? I am a beginner when it comes to python :)

Comment: Yeah, the point of a dictionary is to be able to access values in approximately constant time (i.e. so no looping) when you know the exact key for the value, in which case you do.

Comment: I've explained sets slightly further in my post. It isn't critical to use them, I just did it that way because it was easier for me to write.

Comment: I have syntax error for "set(data[0] for data in data_base[make])" ?/??? parentheses?

Comment: Okay I see, thank you very much for your explanation. Fantastic approach :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably homework and you can't use this answer, but for others looking for the right way to do it, use a `set` for the value and it will automatically only keep unique entries, and use a `defaultdict(set)` for the database.  Then you can directly insert the data.  If the key isn't present the defaultdict will add it with an empty set implicitly.  then `set.add` will insert the new data if unique.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_base = defaultdict(set,{
    "Mercedes": set([("E-class", 1970, "classic", "Germany"),
                     ("Clk"    , 2000, "sport"  , "Poland" )]),
    "Fiat"    : set([("Uno"    , 1980, "coupe"  , "Italy"  )]),
    "Jaguar"  : set([("S-type" , 2000, "classic", "England"),
                     ("X-type" , 2005, "luxury" , "England")])
    })

def functionX(data_base,make,model,year,style,country):
    data_base[make].add((model,year,style,country))
```

Of course the data should also be sanitized for string case, etc.  'classic' and 'Classic' are not the same.